# Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz(x)) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: r, string, format, character, posixlt

I am working on a big satellite fix dataset.
It's the same I used last year with different data, but at some point it stopped working properly showing me this error message: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz(x)) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

This is my line of code:

`pavobreed1 <- pavobreed %>% filter(abandoned != 1)  pavobreed1$remove <- if_else(pavobreed1$Time > pavobreed1$last_fix_breeding_area,"remove","keep") pavobreedfin <- pavobreed1 %>% filter(remove == "keep")`

I am basically trying to create a new column in my dataset with either "keep" or "remove" based on the value of the column "abandoned". The error occurs at the second line of code.

[image: This is part of the dataset I am working on]

Can you help me?
I should note that I already used these same data to perform other POSIXIt formulas with no issues at all.

Comment: It looks like `last_fix_breedung_area` is a character variable. You should convert to POSIXct before the comparison with `Time`.

Comment: Yep you are right, in the end it was that and a strptime function in the format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" that were missing. Thanks!